# arduino,python,pyserial,serial problem error

Tags: python, arduino

I'm doing an arduino project. And I need to make that through python on Arduino the text on Serial was transferred. But there is a problem in the python: (Sorry for the problem with English) (Google Translate)

```
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
time.sleep(1)
while (True):
    print(arduino.readline())
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: The code in the image is not the same as the code in your question. And FYI: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Also, [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you read an Arduino serial:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = str(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break
```

Comment: I changed line 8 make you sure you copy the new code again then test it

Answer (score 0):

In the picture in line 1 you have `serial.Serial as ser:`. That should be `with serial.Serial as ser:`. That should fix the Syntax Error.